# Failed to move file to another directory using renameTo

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String rootPath = "F:\\Java\\Java_Project";
    File fRoot = new File(rootPath);
    File[] fsSub = fRoot.listFiles();

    for (File file : fsSub) {
        if(file.isDirectory()) continue;
        String fileNewPath = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getPath()) + "\\" + file.getName();
        File fNew = new File(fileNewPath);
        try {
            file.renameTo(fNew);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to move the file to another directory,for instance,if the File path is
`"C:\out.txt"`
than I want to move to
`"C:\out\out.txt"`
If i try to print the original File and the new original information, the work well,But they just can not move successful.

Comment: What does `renameTo` return?

Comment: Hi,m0ski0,we are surprise to find that,it returns true,but just do work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to try Java 7 NIO2

```
Files.move(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html